# installation error-Kernel panic

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu from usb drive on my Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop. I am getting an error Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0),what to do?

Comment: I suggest you to re-write this image on usb drive one more time or even use another usb drive. I got this few times to check what happened, few times it will help me.